# KDB/Q functional update using lambda

Tags: kdb

I am trying to use some lambdas in functional updates. Simple example would be

```
parse "update cfoo:foo'[c] from t"

!
`t

falseb
,`cfoo!,((`func;`foo);`c)
```

What is the `func in that parse tree? With what do I need to replace it in below?

```
![`t;();0b;(enlist `cfoo)!enlist ((`func;`foo);`c)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parsing the same thing as you gives me a different thing than what you have:

```
q)parse "update cfoo:foo'[c] from t"
!
`t
()
0b
(,`cfoo)!,((';`foo);`c)
```

Which would look like:

```
![`t;();0b;(enlist`cfoo)!enlist((';`foo);`c)]
```

The above comes straight from the `q prompt. You either parsed a different thing or your GUI/IDE changed something in the final output.

The `func` is nothing else but the `'` you are applying to `[c]`.
Here's an example where I have changed the `'` with something else:

```
q)parse "update cfoo:foo/:[c] from t"
!
`t
()
0b
(,`cfoo)!,((/:;`foo);`c)
```